# Gunicorn site not starting?

Tags: python, virtualenv, wsgi

First let me say that I am a Systems Engineer, but am learning WebDev/DevOps material, with a focus on Python.  Thus, I am in the process of moving my sites over from WordPress (PHP-based), to Mezzanine (Python-based).  To run multiple sites from one VPS, I am setting up VirtualEnv with Gunicorn, and Nginx on the front.  Since my day job is as a SysEngineer and I work with RHEL servers, CentOS 6 is my current web hosting platform of choice.  Here is what I have currently on a CentOS 6.5 server:

```
***INSTALL PYTHON 3.3.4, PIP, VIRTUALENV***
yum groupinstall -y development
yum install -y zlib-dev openssl-devel sqlite-devel bzip2-devel xz-libs
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.4/Python-3.3.4.tar.xz
xz -d Python-3.3.4.tar.xz
tar -xvf Python-3.3.4.tar && cd Python-3.3.4
./configure
make && make altinstall
wget --no-check-certificate https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-2.2.tar.gz
tar -xvf setuptools-2.2.tar.gz && cd setuptools-2.2
python3.3 setup.py install
curl https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | python3.3 -
pip install virtualenv

***SETUP SITES & GUNICORN***
rm -rf /root/Python*
rm -rf /root/setuptools*
mkdir /sites && mkdir /sites/sitename && mkdir /sites/sitename/app && cd /sites/sitename
virtualenv sitename_venv
source sitename_venv/bin/activate
pip install gunicorn
deactivate

***WSGI***
cd /sites/sitename && vi wsgi.py
source sitename_venv/bin/activate
source sitename_venv/bin/activate
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8081 --workers=5 wsgi:app
```

The last section (WSGI) is to test out Gunicorn, and wsgi.py looks like this:

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    """Simplest possible application object"""
    data = 'Hello, World!\n'
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [
        ('Content-type','text/plain'),
        ('Content-Length', str(len(data)))
    ]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return iter([data])
```

So when I start the site, I see this:

```
(sitename_venv)[root@SERVER sitename]# gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8081 --workers=5 wsgi:app
2014-02-22 13:13:07 [36417] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2014-02-22 13:13:07 [36417] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (36417)
2014-02-22 13:13:07 [36417] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2014-02-22 13:13:07 [36420] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 36420
2014-02-22 13:13:07 [36421] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 36421
2014-02-22 13:13:07 [36422] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 36422
2014-02-22 13:13:07 [36423] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 36423
2014-02-22 13:13:07 [36424] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 36424
```

So the site should be running, but when I browse to it (IP:8081 -- from the same network, since this is a local VM and not my VPS yet) I just get "web page not available".  If I stop Gunicorn, I get "Chrome could not connect...blah, blah" so I know Gunicorn is responding to my http request.  What I don't know, is why I can't see what wsgi.py is supposed to be showing?  Any ideas?

Nginx is not in the mix yet, so it's nothing with that config.  I'm still fairly new to virtualenv and python in general, so I wouldn't be surprised if my wsgi.py file has a problem.

Thanks!

EDIT1:

```
[root@SERVER ~]# curl -v http://0:8081
* About to connect() to 0 port 8081 (#0)
*   Trying 0.0.0.0... connected
* Connected to 0 (0.0.0.0) port 8081 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.0.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: 0:8081
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: gunicorn/18.0
< Date: Sat, 22 Feb 2014 18:26:24 GMT
< Connection: close
< Content-type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 14
< 
* transfer closed with 14 bytes remaining to read
* Closing connection #0
curl: (18) transfer closed with 14 bytes remaining to read
```

Comment: Is something in Gunicorn error log, if there is any? What is the output of `curl -v http://0:8081`?

Comment: @Messa EDIT1 in OP shows output of that.  Seems like it's working, but the wsgi.py isn't showing anything.  I'm not sure about logs from Gunicorn as I'm so new to it. I see no Gunicorn logs in /var/logs/* nor anything in /var/logs/messages.

Answer (score 0):

data must be binary in python 3, so encode it before returning

```
return iter([data.encode()])
```